# Can I delete nuget directory on azure app service

Tags: deployment, azure-app-services

I am running a 5 year old ASP.Net Core application on an Azure App Service on the D1 (Shared) app service plan. I have taken care of regular framework and package updates and have recently tried to update to .Net 6.  Everything works fine on the local machine but when trying to deploy through Azure Repos, I get the message:

```
Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with System.Net.WebException: There is not enough space on the disk.
```

Looking at my disk usage I see I am indeed using almost all of the allotted 1 GB.  Investigating with SFTP, I see the .nuget directory has 764 MB in 3,354 directories...

So this is clearly bloated and the result of incremental upgrades over 5 years.

My question is if I can safely delete this directory and let the build process pull whatever it needs for compilation and build? Or is there some other process that needs to be used?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I went ahead and deleted the .nuget directory, and was then able to run a successful deployment.  Interestingly, the new .nuget directory is still large - ~452 MB.